# JavaScript - Processing and restructuring JSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to process a json file and create a new one, but it does not work.

The structure of an old json is something like this:

```
[
    {
       "3":{
        "value":2
        },
        "4":{
            "value":1
        }
    },
    {
       "3":{
        "value":6
        },
        "4":{
            "value":1
        }
    }...and so on
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new json object, which will have only two objects 0 and 1 and inside each of them there will be values from indexes 3 and 4 from the old one, which should look something like this:

```
{
    "0":{
        "0":[
            {
                "0":2
            }
        ],
        "1":[
            {
                "0":6
            }
        ]..and so on
    },
    "1":{
        "0":[
            {
              "0":1
            }
        ],
        "1":[
        {
            "0":1
        }
        ]..and so on
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I process and cook the old json the output for both indexes(0,1) is the same. I'm trying to loop it through 3 and 4 and assign those values into the new array but something is not quite right.

Fraction of the code:

```
//loop through the keysIndex
for (var c in keysIndex) {
    //the new json has to be 2 objects, hence the below
    newData[c] = {};
    var vallueArr = [];
    var newObj = {
        0: oldData[i][keysIndex[c]].value
    }
    vallueArr.push(newObj);
    objInNewData[entries] = vallueArr;
    //the problem is somehwere here, it is appending twice the same
    //objInNewData and not both 3 and 4 individually
    newData[c] = objInNewData;
}
```

Hers's the whole logic: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/TaRsqGufDMNgpidxtOrz?p=preview)

Can someone please help as I cannot get my head around this :(

Many thanks

Comment: how do you know, that 3 maps to 0 and 4 to 1?

Comment: This data structure seems odd to me. since you use numbers in your object keys would it make more sense to have `[[{value: 'foo'}, {value: 'foo2'} ...], ...]`?

Comment: @NinaScholz because I have created an array with (3 and 4) which should loop and map it through. It's in the plunker. Any idea how can this be solved? I just need that output being that way unfortunately.

Comment: @angular_learner, you generate the array `keysIndex` dynamic on each iteration, how can you make sure, that the keys are always the same? or is it given?

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes it is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, the use of index of keys of objects is not a good idea, because objects in Javascript have no defined order. For ordered items I suggest to use an array instead.

```js
var data = [
        {
            "3": { "value": 2 },
            "4": { "value": 1 }
        }, {
            "3": { "value": 6 },
            "4": { "value": 1 }
        }
    ],
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]), // <-- ATTENTION!
    obj = {};

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    keys.forEach(function (k, j) {
        obj[j] = obj[j] || {};
        obj[j][i] = obj[j][i] || [];
        obj[j][i].push({ '0': a[k].value });
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Wow, you are star! Thank you so much! :)